# Bash - select lines of a file based on values in another file

Tags: bash, select

I have 2 files; let's call them file1 and file2. file1 contains a start and an end coordinate in each row, e.g.:

```
start end
2000 2696
3465 3688
8904 9546
```

etc.

file2 has several columns, of which the first is the most relevant for the question:

```
position v2 v3 v4
3546 value12 value13 value14
9847 value22 value23 value24
12000 value32 value33 value34
```

Now, I need to output a new file, which will contain only the lines of file2 for which the 'position' value (1st column) is in between the 'start' and the 'end' value of any of the columns of file1. In R I'd just make a double loop, but it takes too much time (the files are large), so need to do it in bash. In case the question is unclear, here's the R loop that would do the job:

```
for(i in 1:dim(file1)[1]){
for(j in 1:dim(file2)[1]){
if(file2[j,1]>file1$start[i] & file2[j,1]<file1$end[i]) file2$select=1 else file2$select=0
}
}
```

Very sure there's a simple way of doing this using bash / awk...

Comment: `join` will NOT do it for you :). I wonder if there is anything else

Comment: This is a one-liner if "awk" is allowed. Is it?

Answer (score 2):

The awk will look like this, but you'll need to remove the first line from file1 and file2 first:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{x[i]=$1;y[i++]=$2;next}{for(j=0;j<i;j++){if($1>=x[j]&&$1<=y[j]){print $0}}}' file1 file2
```

The bit in curly braces after "FNR==NR" only applies to the processing of file1 and it says to store field1 in array x[] and field2 in array y[] so we have the upper and lower bounds of each range. The bit in the second set of curly braces applies to procesing file2 only. It says to iterate through all the bounds in array x[] and y[] and see if field1 is between the bounds, and print the whole reocrd if it is.

If you don't want to remove the header line at the start, you can make the awk a little more complicated and ignore it like this:

```
awk 'FNR==1{next}FNR==NR{x[i]=$1;y[i++]=$2;next}{for(j=0;j<i;j++){if($1>=x[j]&&$1<=y[j]){print $0}}}' file1 file2
```

**EDITED**

Ok, I have added code to check "chromosome" (whatever that is!) assuming it is in the first field in both files, like this:

File1

```
x 2000 2696
x 3465 3688
x 8904 9546
```

File2

```
x 3546 value12 value13 value14
y 3467 value12 value13 value14
x 9847 value22 value23 value24
x 12000 value32 value33 value34
```

So the code now stores the chromosome in array c[] as well and checks they are equal before outputting.

```
awk 'BEGIN{i=0}FNR==NR{c[i]=$1;x[i]=$2;y[i++]=$3;next}{for(j=0;j<i;j++){if(c[j]==$1&&$2>=x[j]&&$2<=y[j]){print $0;next}}}' file1 file2
```

Comment: Nice line of awk. If the intervals on file1 don't overlap sorting the first file will allow to speed up a lot the execution exitting the loop over file1 (files have several million lines!)

Comment: If the entries in file2 are monotonically increasing, you could speed up this some more by just checking one index, then incrementing it when you go past it. If file1 is large, the gains could be significant.

Comment: Hm, the code outputs more lines than file2 had to begin with (it should be a few orders of magnitude less). I get 2.7 million lines back; file2 was 2.6 million.

Comment: @Mark Setchell - any idea why this is?

Comment: It should also work faster now because it stops searching as soon as it finds the first range that matches whereas before each line of file2 could be printed multiple times if it matched multiple ranges in file1. Also not sure if the test should be "less than", or "less than or equal". If field 2 in file2 is seven and file1 specified a range of 7-11 should the record be printed or not?

Comment: You are welcome to Email me a sample of your files if there are any problems, or you want to discuss further (mark at thesetchells dot com)

Comment: If it all works nicely now, can you please accept my answer so I get a lovely big green tick? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how to do this in bash...

I would try a perl script, reading the first file and storing it in memory (if it's possible, it depends on its size) and then going through the second file line by line and doing the comparisons to output the line or not.

I think you can do this in R too... the same way: storing the first file, looping for each line of the second file .

Moreover if the intervals don't overlap, you can do a sort on the files to speed up your algorithm.

Comment: Yeah, I've done it in R (loop posted above, just to clarify the question), but it's too slow -- the files are huge so need bash/awk.

Answer (score 0):

This should be faster than the `for` loop

```
res <- apply(file2, 1, function(row)
            {
            any(row$position > file1$start & row$position < file1$end)
            })
```

Comment: Yes, did that too. Still too slow, so have to use bash/awk.

Comment: (It's a file with several million lines)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the delimiters for the files are spaces (if not - change -d estting).

The script uses `cut` to extract the first field of file2.
Then a simple grep searches for the field in file1. If present, the line from file2 is printed.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
    word=$(echo $line | cut -f1 -d" ")
    grep -c $word file1 >/dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
       echo "$line"
    fi
done < file2
```

Comment: I think you have to test whether the field1 is BETWEEN the ranges in the first file, but there is no range test in your code...

Comment: Yeah it looked like that to me too.